# Tray application not displaying properly

Tags: vb.net, system-tray

Below I have the code for a framework I am working with. The problem I am having is that the Icon will not show up in the system tray unless the commented code is included. The weirdest part is that the other lines of code for the notifyicon1 properties will then work. Can someone please help me understand what is going on?

```
 Public Class Main

Public WithEvents notifyicon1 As New NotifyIcon

Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Width = 1200
    Height = 850
    ShowIcon = True
    Me.Text = "V1.0.0.0"

    ' icon
    Icon = My.Resources.icon_4

    'set the form properties
    BackColor = Color.White

    Dim start As New startup()

End Sub

Private Sub Main_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
        notifyicon1.Visible = True
        Me.Hide()
        Icon = My.Resources.icon_4
        notifyicon1.Visible = True
        notifyicon1.BalloonTipText = "Hi from right system tray"
        notifyicon1.ShowBalloonTip(500)

        'With notifyicon1
        '    .Icon = My.Resources.icon_4
        '    .Visible = True
        '    .ShowBalloonTip(500)
        'End With


    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NotifyIcon1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles notifyicon1.DoubleClick
    Me.Show()
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    notifyicon1.Visible = False
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: The NotifyIcon will not show up when you forget to set its Icon property.  You need to do this up front, use the designer or the constructor of your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans pointed out, you need to set the notifyicon1's Icon property, which you do in the With statement, but not in the code above.

Change the `Icon = My.Resources.icon_4` with `notifyicon1.Icon = My.Resources.icon_4`, as you don't seem to be using the Icon property anywhere.